# How to use JSTL tags without using jsp UseBean

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, xss, el

I have a problem where i am supposed to stop XSS vulnerabilities . A typical example here is in  `vulnerable.jsp` :

```
 <h2><%= myObj.getElf() %></h2>
```

The `myObj` is an object of the `kObj class` , which i have created in the jsp file :

```
<% kObj myObj = KSession.getPostInfo(session); %>
```

The problem here is there is no  use of use bean  here in this framework. As a result usage of   core JSTl becomes troubling and it does not work. For e.g when i try to do :

```
<h2><c:out value={$( myObj.elf)} /></h2>
```

It does not work and tells me that there is no value for the object `elf` with the `.` operator.

The  `kObj` class is not strictly a POJO as well. Can some one suggest what i can do here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSTL tags as demonstrated in your code use EL.  Objects used in EL should be in one of the known scopes: request, session, etc.  So in your EL expression, you should try using the key with which the instance was actually stored in the session rather than myObj.

You seem to be getting the object from the HTTP Session, not sure what KSession is, but I assume it internally gets it from the session map.  Lets assume the actual key by which the object is stored in the session map is "myObjKey". So instead of using "${myobj.elf}" use "${myObjKey.elf}"

Comment: So you mean to say : i must use something like `<h2><c:out value={$( session.key)} /></h2>` ?

Comment: Edited for further clarification.